# How do I access the Error code from Node.js error?

Tags: node.js

I'm using the `uncaughtException` event of `process` to detect errors. The provided error object does not have the `code` property, but the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_code) says that `code` is a property of the `Error` class. Is the error object provided by `uncaughtException` different from the `Error` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the error which is caught, i.e. not all errors actually have the `code` property set.
Consider the following two simple examples:

```
// example 1
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
    console.log(error)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

If something else is already listening on the 3000 port, the following error-info will be printed to the console:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1298:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1346:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1434:7)
    ...
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
```

As you can see the [system error](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_systemerror) `EADDRINUSE` has a code property set.

On the other hand this

```
// example 2
process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
    console.log(error)
});

someFunc();
```

will print:

```
ReferenceError: someFunc is not defined
    ...
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

As you can see [ReferenceError](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_referenceerror) does not have the code-property set.

Comment: What about SyntaxError?

Comment: Just try it in a test :) You'll see that they also don*t have the code-property set - same as RefernceError.